# ¿Cómo imprimir valores de otra variable en dataTable JSF?

Tags: java, html, jsf, mvc, primefaces

Hola estoy intentando generar una tabla en JSF usando BootsFaces.

Yo comprendo que si quiero imprimir una lista que tengo en un Bean, dentro del dataTable se puede definir una variable para iterar en cada elemento, pero **¿cómo puedo imprimir otros valores de otra lista dentro del mismo dataTable?**

La tabla básicamente imprime una postulación, y por cada postulación, se asocian 3 imágenes.

Mi código se ve así:

```
<b:dataTable value="#{misServCtrl.listaPostulaCliente}" var="p" lang="es">
  <b:dataTableColumn value="#{p.idPostulacion}" label="Número" />
  <b:dataTableColumn label="Soportes">
    <c:if test="#{misServCtrl.listaImagenes != null}">
        <c:forEach items="#{misServCtrl.listaImagenes}" var="listImg">
            <c:forEach items="#{listImg}" var="img">
                <p:lightBox>
                    <h:outputLink value="img_soporte/#{img.imagenNombre}" title="Soporte 1">  
                        <b:button value="Soporte 1" look="default" icon-awesome="picture-o" />
                    </h:outputLink>
                    <h:outputLink value="img_soporte/#{img.imagenNombre}" title="Soporte 2">  
                        <b:button value="Soporte 2" look="default" icon-awesome="picture-o" />
                    </h:outputLink>
                    <h:outputLink value="img_soporte/#{img.imagenNombre}" title="Soporte 3">  
                        <b:button value="Soporte 3" look="default" icon-awesome="picture-o" />
                    </h:outputLink>
                </p:lightBox>
            </c:forEach>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:if>
  </b:dataTableColumn>
```

Tuve que crear una Lista de Listas para traer una consulta; por cada postulación, asociar una lista de tres Objetos que son las imágenes.

Ya que es una matriz, decidí imprimir dentro de dos forEach, peor no funcionó (a pesar de que la consulta sí me trae datos).

¿Alguien me pudiese ayudar con esto?

Answer (score 0):

Solo como dato, el primer bucle for each ya te esta devolviendo las imagenes, te sobra el segundo bucle:

```
        <c:forEach items="#{misServCtrl.listaImagenes}" var="img">
                <p:lightBox>
                    <h:outputLink value="img_soporte/#{img.imagenNombre}" title="Soporte 1">  
                        <b:button value="Soporte 1" look="default" icon-awesome="picture-o" />
                    </h:outputLink>
                   ...
                </p:lightBox>
        </c:forEach>
```

Dicho esto, para hacer esto no puedes usar JSTL (c:if o c:forEach) ya que estas etiquetas(build-time tags) se evaluan en la View Built fase y las etiquetas de JSF(render-time tags) se evaluan en la View Render fase lo que quiere decir que tus bucles no se estan evaluando ya que el componente digamos que aún no esta lleno, para esto debes usar

```
...
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"...

<b:dataTable value="#{misServCtrl.listaPostulaCliente}" var="p" lang="es">
  <b:dataTableColumn value="#{p.idPostulacion}" label="Número" />
  <b:dataTableColumn label="Soportes">

        <ui:repeat var="img" rendered="#{not empty misServCtrl.listaImagenes}" value="#{misServCtrl.listaImagenes}" >

                <p:lightBox>
                    <h:outputLink value="img_soporte/#{img.imagenNombre}" title="Soporte 1">  
                        <b:button value="Soporte 1" look="default" icon-awesome="picture-o" />
                    </h:outputLink>
                    <h:outputLink value="img_soporte/#{img.imagenNombre}" title="Soporte 2">  
                        <b:button value="Soporte 2" look="default" icon-awesome="picture-o" />
                    </h:outputLink>
                    <h:outputLink value="img_soporte/#{img.imagenNombre}" title="Soporte 3">  
                        <b:button value="Soporte 3" look="default" icon-awesome="picture-o" />
                    </h:outputLink>
                </p:lightBox>

        </ui:repeat>
  </b:dataTableColumn>
```

Con eso ya debería funcionar. Un saludo